# Android OS on Virtual Server or Container

Tags: android, docker, virtualization

Can we run Android OS as guest OS on a virtual server (Google Cloud, EC2)? 
Can we run Android OS inside a container?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: For purely academic purpose, I am trying to run a VM with Android OS as a Guest Operating System and connect to it through VNC. The instance should launch Firefox/Chrome on connecting

Comment: This is a good question, but please add you comment in OP for background and clarity. The topic is indeed very useful for many other reasons, like security testing of apps etc.

Answer (score 1):

The Android SDK comes with the Android Emulator, this is a virtual machine running Android.

The SDK comes with both ARM and Intel x86 versions of the Virtual machine.

The emulator is based on the qemu emulator.

You may also want to read this answer to a similar closed question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20870262/504554

People have also managed to install Android x86 into VirtualBox VMs. Early on the emulator was very slow (when it only supported ARM builds) and this was used as a way to work quicker while developing.